# Accessing multilevel json data in Django

Tags: python, json, django

I have a problem with one part of json file i need to use.

json file looks more or less like that:

```
"name1": {
    "item1":{
        "value1": "value"
        "value2": "value"
        ...

"name2": [
    {
        "item1":[
            {
                "value1": "value"
                "value2": "value"
                ...
```

Values in "name1" can be easily accessible.

views.py

```
#response to string
r = res.text
j = json.loads(r)

x = standings["name1"]
y = standings["name2"]
```

then i return x to template, and then i can iterate through data like that:

```
{% for key, value in x.items %}
```

but that doesn't work for "name2". "name1" is Dict, "name2" is list.
In template i can't access values in name2. I have to show, both "item1" string from "name2", and all values inside "item1".

How can i do that?

Comment: why is name1 a dict, and name2 a list? the structure of the data seems weird

Comment: Can't do anything with that, that's how it's in API.

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

given the data structure you provided:

```
    data = {
    "name1": {
        "item1": {
            "value1": "name1 value",
            "value2": "name value"
        }
    },
    "name2": [
        {
            "item1": {
                "value1": "name2 value",
                "value2": "value"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

you can access the values of name2 in a template like this:

```
{% for item in data.name2 %}
  # access directly 
  {{ item.item1.value1 }}
  {{ item.item1.value2 }} 
    # or if you want to iter
     {% for k,v in item.item1.items %} 
        key is {{ k }} value is {{ v }} 
      {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Although, I don't see why the first item is a dict, and the second item is a list...

Comment: Problem starts when name of "item1" is for example "firstname surname" with space in it. That's the issue here too. Sadly, that's how it is in API, can't do anything with that.

Comment: you may need to create a custom template tag then,  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-template-tags/